# Google Assistant(Dialogflow)で1回の要求に対して、2回応答する方法について

Tags: google-api, google-cloud

私はGoogle Assistant(Dialogflow)でユーザからの要求に対して、2回レスポンスをしたいと考えています。

例えば以下の通りです。
＝＝＝
1. ユーザが「天気を教えて」と発話

2-1. ユーザへ「調べますのでお待ちください」と返答 *response 1*
2-2. Dialogflow(Webhook)で天気のWebAPIを呼び出す（処理に5秒程かかる想定）

～5秒後～

3. ユーザへ「今日の天気は晴れです」と返答 *response 2*
   ＝＝＝

そこで質問です。
(1)上記のように1回の要求に対して、2回レスポンスを返すことは可能ですか？
(2)可能な場合、具体的にどのようにすれば良いか教えてください。
(3)不可能な場合、上記を実現するための案を教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

単に回答の中で数秒間あけるだけであれば、SSMLのbreak要素を使うことで可能ですが、ご希望の「回答→処理→回答」を実現するための機能は、Actions on Googleで公開されている範囲においては現時点では見当たりません。

[Updates and Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates)（まだBetaです）を使えば、アプリから能動的にユーザに何かを言うことができるようになりますが、事前にユーザから同意を得る必要があります。また、現時点では日本語ロケールではうまく機能していませんので、もう少し安定するまで待つ必要がありそうです。